# What is the notation for equivalent cardinalities?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In NBG class theory, for any set $a$ we can define the class $V_a$ of all sets $b$ such that there is a bijection $f: a \to b.$

$a$ and $b$ have equivalent cardinalities if $b \in V_a$ (or $a \in V_b$). One way to write this is
$$|a| = |b|.$$
Using the von Neumann cardinal assignment, what $|a| = |b|$ *means* is that the least ordinal number in bijection with $a$ equals the least ordinal number in bijection with $b$. The ordinal $|a|$ is a canonical representative in $V_a$, and when we say $|a| = |b|$ we're saying the canonical representative of $V_a$ equals the canonical representative of $V_b$, so $V_a = V_b$.

My question is: is there an established equivalence symbol for $|a| = |b|$ without using $| \cdot |$? I should be able to say two sets are equivalent (equinumerous) without referring to any particular representatives.

For example, "$a \overset{\#}{=} b$", with the meaning "there is a bijection from $a$ to $b$."

Comment: Your description of $|a|=|b|$ is not correct. What this *means* is that the LEAST ordinal number in bijection with $a$ equals the LEAST ordinal number in bijection with $b$.

Comment: Thank you! Edited to reflect your correction.

Comment: I am perfectly comfortable using $|a|=|b|$ to mean that there is a bijection between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott and I am perfectly comfortable using $\overline{a} = \overline{b}$ to mean $a + n\mathbb{Z} = b + n \mathbb{Z}$ (in the context of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, of course). But I nevertheless think $a \equiv b$ is useful notation.

Comment: @CTVK: In that case I consider the contexts in which the two notations are likely to be used to be sufficiently different to warrant having different notations emphasizing different aspects; in the case of cardinality I don’t, save perhaps for situations rare enough that it makes more sense to define a nonce usage like $a\approx b$ or $a\sim b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen

$$a\approx b\qquad \text{or}\qquad a\approx_f b$$

where $f$ is the witness (i.e. the bijection) of the equinumerous relation.

I prefer to use

$$a\sim b$$

because I also like to use
$$a\lesssim b$$
to indicate that there exists an injection from $a$ to $b$ which is a partial ordering due  to [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem):$$a\lesssim b\lesssim a\implies a\sim b$$
To answer your question, there is no established *relation* symbol. Although $|a|=|b|$ and $\#a=\#b$ are quite standard in my opinion.